# How much RAM does my netlogo model needs?

Tags: cluster-computing, netlogo, ram, monitor

I'm building a model based on a very large GIS map. I'm building it on a smaller portion of the map because the shapefile won't even load in Netlogo installed on my computer (I already modified the space needed in the JVM settings).

I have access to a large calculation platform which is a cluster of processor.
(I understood that one model is running on one processor only)
To be able to use the cluster, **I must evaluate how much RAM and time the model would need.**

1. how can I monitor the RAM usage in netlogo as we monitor the time ?
2. would you have advices/rule of thumbs about the extrapolation of RAM and time from a small simulated dataset to a larger one ?
   I believe that I should do it procedures by procedures, and depending on the commands, "multiplying by the number of extra patches".

For the background, I'm not a computing engineer, I'm a researcher in agronomy/hydrology that do modeling. Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

From the netlogo-users google group, I got the answer that I should just use the "Task Manager" tool from Windows and monitor the specific memory usage of netlogo when running the model.